# How can i filter a list of divs when 2 checkboxes are checked using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of 4 divs and i use 2 checkboxes to filter the list by the existence of specific divs. The filtering works perfect until i check both 2 checkboxes.

As you can see in my code below if you try to check both "Card" & "Paypal" checkboxes the list is disappeared. Instead i need to display all of 4 divs. How can i make it work this way?

Here's the code:

```js
$("#by-card").change(function() {
  $('.store-block .store-payment-options').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.card-available').length === 0) {
      $(this).parent(".store-block").toggleClass('hide-me');
    }
  });
});



$("#by-paypal").change(function() {
  $('.store-block .store-payment-options').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.paypal-available').length === 0) {
      $(this).parent(".store-block").toggleClass('hide-me');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.search-area {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.storesList {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#count {
  display: inline-block;
}

.store-block {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 3px;
}

.minorder {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 3px;
}

.paypal-available,
.card-available {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-lab {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes-area">
  <div class=" inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-card">
    <label for="by-card">Card</label>
  </div>

  <div class=" inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-paypal">
    <label for="by-paypal">Paypal</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="storesList">
  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.5</div>
    <div class="minorder">100 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 3.8</div>
    <div class="minorder">250 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.0</div>
    <div class="minorder">25 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Linux</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.9</div>
    <div class="minorder">50 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because neither `Card` nor `Paypal` are checked initially, would this mean that you would want none of the divs to be displayed initially (or when both checkboxes become unchecked)?

Comment: @CertainPerformance i dont want them checked by default (initialy). I just want them show all of flitered divs when someone have checked both of checkboxes

Comment: You probably meant to reply to me, @CertainPerformance. I wasn't talking about their initial checked state (which is, of course, unchecked), I'm talking about whether the divs should be hidden by default, if you want your checkboxes to perform like an "or" operator.

Comment: @CertainPerformance my bad about mentioning your username, so sorry. I want the divs visible by default(on page load).

Comment: You can check the status of another checkbox before toggle a css class. Please try to add the condition. Off: radio will be better I think

Comment: @toor Radio buttons worked perfect but i really need checkboxes here. Also i tried something like if ($("#by-card").is(':checked') == true) but didnt work. I will try again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Designer you can look at my suggested answer. Maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good at jQuery, but here's how I'd solve that using good old plain vanilla Javascript. The key change to your approach is to listen for the `change` event on a **parent element** of both checkboxes (instead of on each **checkbox** with a seperate handler), then check if **either**, or **both**, or no **checkboxes** are checked, and create the appropriate DOM state accordingly:

```js
var checkboxArea = document.querySelector('.checkboxes-area')
var storeBlocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.store-block'))
var byCard = document.getElementById('by-card')
var byPaypal = document.getElementById('by-paypal')

var cardBlocks = storeBlocks.filter(function(block) {
  return block.querySelector('.card-available')
})

var payPalBlocks = storeBlocks.filter(function(block) {
  return block.querySelector('.paypal-available')
})

checkboxArea.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  switch (true) {
    case byCard.checked && byPaypal.checked:
      storeBlocks.forEach(function(block) { block.classList.remove('hide-me') })
      break
    case byCard.checked:
      cardBlocks.forEach(function(block) { block.classList.remove('hide-me') })
      payPalBlocks.forEach(function(block) { block.classList.add('hide-me') })
      break
    case byPaypal.checked:
      cardBlocks.forEach(function(block) { block.classList.add('hide-me') })
      payPalBlocks.forEach(function(block) { block.classList.remove('hide-me') })
      break  
    default:
      payPalBlocks.concat(cardBlocks).forEach(function(block) { block.classList.remove('hide-me') })
  }
})
```

```css
.search-area {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.storesList {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#count {
  display: inline-block;
}

.store-block {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 3px;
}

.minorder {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 3px;
}

.paypal-available,
.card-available {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-lab {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes-area">
  <div class="inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-card">
    <label for="by-card">Card</label>
  </div>

  <div class="inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-paypal">
    <label for="by-paypal">Paypal</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="storesList">
  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.5</div>
    <div class="minorder">100 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 3.8</div>
    <div class="minorder">250 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.0</div>
    <div class="minorder">25 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Linux</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.9</div>
    <div class="minorder">50 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice approach but i m limited to use jquery on my project so i can't select your answer as the best. Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Such projects don't exist. Only because jQuery is *available* and *used*  on your project doesn't **limit** you to that. Javascript is **always** available. The less dependant you code base is on jQuery, the better (imo).

Comment: Also note how this code needs only a single event handler to register because it capitalizes on the fact that `change` events bubble up the DOM.

Comment: I agree your code is very clean and ease to understant.

Comment: Finally i 'll pick your answer as the best @connexo. Also i added the tag "javascript" in my question.
Once again thank you so much.

Comment: @Designer Glad to see you're open to doing things differently than what you're used to. This kind of openmindedness is what a developer needs to progresss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180103/discussion-between-designer-and-connexo).

Answer (score 2):

To get that behaviour you need to change the code which you have:

1. You need to have a single `change` function for the checkboxes of `paypal` and `card`
2. Then whenever any of the checkbox is checked/unchecked, you can loop both the checkboxes to know if any of them is checked. If you get the checkbox checked then show the elements with class `store-block` where I have also added one more class same as the `id` value of the `checkbox` that is clicked.
3. Using this class value it will be easy to determine the set of divs that belong to the particular checkbox.
4. You also need to manage the scenario when all the checkbox are unchecked after they were checked so, for that I have used a variable `oneChecked`.

```js
$(".inputRadioGroup input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var oneChecked = false;
  $(".inputRadioGroup input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    var checked = this.checked;
    var checkedId = $(this).attr('id');
    if(checked){
      oneChecked = true;
      $('.'+checkedId).show();
    } else {
      $('.'+checkedId).hide();
    }
  });
  if(!oneChecked){
    $('.store-block').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.search-area {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.storesList {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#count {
  display: inline-block;
}

.store-block {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 3px;
}

.minorder {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 3px;
}

.paypal-available,
.card-available {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-lab {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes-area">

  <div class="inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-card">
    <label for="by-card">Card</label>
  </div>


  <div class="inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-paypal">
    <label for="by-paypal">Paypal</label>
  </div>


</div>


<div class="storesList">

  <div class="store-block by-card">
    <div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.5</div>
    <div class="minorder">100 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block by-paypal">
    <div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 3.8</div>
    <div class="minorder">250 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block by-card">
    <div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.0</div>
    <div class="minorder">25 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block by-paypal">
    <div class="store-name">Linux</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.9</div>
    <div class="minorder">50 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this result without change the html code? This is very important.

Comment: The change in HTML is not major. You are adding a new class there. Which is not for CSS designs but for the use of JS @Designer