# How can i filter a list of divs when 3 or more checkboxes are checked using jquery or even plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Based on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342832/how-can-i-filter-a-list-of-divs-when-2-checkboxes-are-checked-using-jquery-or-ja/52343038#52343038) of mine i want to filter a list of divs by different combinations based on the existence of specific div elements.

In the below example i use 3 checkboxes "Card", "Paypal", "Show only open stores" to filter the list. As it is now it works for the "Card" & "Paypal" checkboxes but if you try to check also the "Show only open stores" checkbox it messing it up. How can i fix that?

Here's the code:

```js
var checkboxArea = document.querySelector('.filter-area')
var storeBlocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.store-block'))
var byCard = document.getElementById('by-card')
var byPaypal = document.getElementById('by-paypal')
var byOpen = document.getElementById('by-open')

var cardBlocks = storeBlocks.filter(function(block) {
  return block.querySelector('.card-available')
})

var payPalBlocks = storeBlocks.filter(function(block) {
  return block.querySelector('.paypal-available')
})

var openStoreBlocks = storeBlocks.filter(function(block) {
  return block.querySelector('.close-small-tag')
})

checkboxArea.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  switch (true) {
    case byCard.checked && byPaypal.checked:
      storeBlocks.forEach(function(block) {
        block.classList.remove('hide-me')
      })
      break
    case byCard.checked:
      cardBlocks.forEach(function(block) {
        block.classList.remove('hide-me')
      })
      payPalBlocks.forEach(function(block) {
        block.classList.add('hide-me')
      })
      break
    case byPaypal.checked:
      cardBlocks.forEach(function(block) {
        block.classList.add('hide-me')
      })
      payPalBlocks.forEach(function(block) {
        block.classList.remove('hide-me')
      })
      break

    case byOpen.checked:
      openStoreBlocks.forEach(function(block) {
        block.classList.toggle('hide-me')
      })
      break



    default:
      payPalBlocks.concat(cardBlocks).forEach(function(block) {
        block.classList.remove('hide-me')
      })
  }
})
```

```css
.close-small-tag,
.open-small-tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: 130px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: brown;
}

.search-area {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.storesList {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#count {
  display: inline-block;
}

.store-block {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: 3px;
}

.minorder {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 3px;
}

.paypal-available,
.card-available {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.hide-me {
  display: none;
}

.filter-area {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inputRadioGroup {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-area">

  <div class=" inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-card">
    <label for="by-card">Card</label>
  </div>


  <div class=" inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-paypal">
    <label for="by-paypal">Paypal</label>
  </div>

  <div class=" inputRadioGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="by-open">
    <label for="by-open">SHOW ONLY OPEN STORES</label>
  </div>


</div>


<div class="storesList">

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Apple Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.5</div>
    <div class="open-small-tag">OPEN</div>
    <div class="minorder">100 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Nokia Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 3.8</div>
    <div class="open-small-tag">OPEN</div>
    <div class="minorder">250 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Samsung Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.0</div>
    <div class="close-small-tag">CLOSE</div>
    <div class="minorder">25 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="card-available">CARD</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="store-block">
    <div class="store-name">Linux Store</div>
    <div class="rating">&bigstar; 4.9</div>
    <div class="close-small-tag">CLOSE</div>
    <div class="minorder">50 €</div>
    <div class="store-payment-options">
      <div class="paypal-available">PAYPAL</div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: The current approach doesn't work that well due to overlapping of the criterions which wasn't the case in your previous question. I'd recommend if your frontend starts to become more complex, you should consider using something like Vue.js to program this piece of your application.

Comment: Sidenote: Your question really shows why it is a bad idea to have complex application logic realized in DOM logic. It just becomes a total mess far too quickly.

Comment: What would be a good solution to handle such cases?

Comment: This by far exceeds a simple StackOverflow answer. If I were hired on your project, I'd teach you and your fellows an MVC/MVVM-based approach that makes this - and far more complex stuff - alot easier. The difference in the development approach is that you stop thinking about DOM, and instead start thinking about a data structure that's suitable so your can generate the HTML off it. That way, all you do is bind your HTML to certain states of the date with regard to filter options being enabled/disabled.